# How do I make my python script communicate with my MSP430 launchpad?

Tags: python, python-3.x, msp430

I want to create a GUI in python and make it interact with my micro-controller board(MSP430G2).
Would like to know if there is any way to send/receive data between the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install python-msp430-tools

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from msp430.util import hexdump
    import time
    mmc = MMC()
    try:
        mmc.connect()
        print mmc.info()
        #show what's there
        hexdump((0, mmc.read(0)))
        #speed test
        t1 = time.time()
        for n in range(10):
            mmc.read(n)
        t2 = time.time()
        dt = t2 - t1
        bytes = n * 512
        print "%d bytes in %.2f seconds -> %.2f bytes/second" % (bytes, dt, bytes/dt)
    finally:
        mmc.release()
```

[python-msp430-tools](https://github.com/zsquareplusc/python-msp430-tools/tree/master/examples)